# How to change the text input color of "prompt" method in Cordova?

Tags: cordova

Using `navigator.dialogs.prompt` method, the typing dialog appears on the screen, but the text is white (same color as background) so the user cannot see what is typing.

I'm using pure Cordova. What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Rodolfo in the comments, the solution:

1. Open `./platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/dialogs/Notification.java`
2. Replace `THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT` with `THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK`
3. Execute `cordova platform remove android && cordova platform add android` to pick up the changes
4. Execute `cordova build android` to rebuild

Answer (score 1):

It's a well known bug. You can try to modify 
platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/dialogs/Notification.java :
search for "public synchronized void prompt"
 after " promptInput.setHint(defaultText);" add " promptInput.setHintTextColor(0xff888888);"

Or you can use another version of this plugin, with different theme like: https://github.com/ecorona/cordova-plugin-dialogs-dark

Also you can write your own dialog plugin using Native UI options. There is a fine introduction for begginers at: https://blogs.oracle.com/mobile/entry/introduction_to_custom_cordova_plugin

Comment: first alternative, the text color keeps white.

Comment: Yes. It seems to me the file is ignored on compiling.

Comment: @Darkroon I changed lines 479 and 489, from `THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT` to `THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK`. It seems ok now.

Comment: Good to know! Good luck in future development!

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add :

```
promptInput.setTextColor(0xff888888);
```

after

```
promptInput.setHint(defaultText);
```